# iOS CIFilters which actually do work?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, filter, cifilter

I am currently trying to populate a collection view with a picture which is filtered by different CIFilters.
I used apples way to get an array of filters.

```
let filterNames = CIFilter.filterNamesInCategories([kCICategoryStillImage,kCICategoryBuiltIn])
```

I thought this should give me all filters which are applicable to still images on the iPhone.
But it kinda doesn't work.

This are (some) of the filters i get from the method above:

```
["CIAccordionFoldTransition", "CIAdditionCompositing", "CIAffineClamp", "CIAffineTile", "CIAffineTransform", "CIAreaAverage", "CIAreaHistogram", "CIAreaMaximum", "CIAreaMaximumAlpha", "CIAreaMinimum", "CIAreaMinimumAlpha", "CIAztecCodeGenerator", "CIBarsSwipeTransition", "CIBlendWithAlphaMask", "CIBlendWithMask", "CIBloom", "CIBoxBlur", "CIBumpDistortion", "CIBumpDistortionLinear", "CICheckerboardGenerator", "CICircleSplashDistortion", "CICircularScreen", "CICircularWrap", "CICMYKHalftone",
```

plus A LOT more.

I apply the filters with this method:

```
func applyFilter(image: UIImage, filterName: String) -> UIImage {

    let beginImage = CIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage!)

    let filter = CIFilter(name: filterName)!

    filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    filter.setDefaults()

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let imageRef = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, fromRect: beginImage.extent)

    let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
    return newImage
}
```

The first two filters wont work because the resulting image is a nil, then some work, and then i get:

```
[<CIAztecCodeGenerator 0x7fb89c775460> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this     class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputImage.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd5de65     __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010efebdeb    objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd5daa9 -   [NSException raise] + 9
3   CoreImage                           0x000000010d33eea2 -[CIFilter setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 137
4   CoreImage                           0x000000010d4093ce -[CIAztecCodeGenerator setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 335
5   Foundation                          0x000000010d6749bb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
6   DrawIt                              0x000000010cb55088 _TFC6DrawIt25applyFilterViewController11applyFilterfS0_FTCSo7UIImage10filterNameSS_S1_ + 552
7   DrawIt                              0x000000010cb54b52 _TFC6DrawIt25applyFilterViewController14collectionViewfS0_FTCSo16UICollectionView22cellForItemAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 1186
8   DrawIt                              0x000000010cb54e3f _TToFC6DrawIt25applyFilterViewController14collectionViewfS0_FTCSo16UICollectionView22cellForItemAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 79
9   UIKit                               0x000000010e31d5ba -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:] + 483
10  UIKit                               0x000000010e31fae0 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4431
11  UIKit                               0x000000010e32423b -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 247
12  UIKit                               0x000000010db7f4a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113d0059a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113cf4e70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113cf4cee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113ce9475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113d16c0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113d259f4 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 576
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccbdc84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccbd831 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1089
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc7f241 __CFRunLoopRun + 1937
22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc7e828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
23  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113bc8ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
24  UIKit                               0x000000010dac8610 UIApplicationMain + 171
25  DrawIt                              0x000000010cb569fd main + 109
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010faf492d start + 1
27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I did not check all the rest of the filters. 
I thought that the array SHOULD only contain flters which are applicable easy as that. 
Is it the code thats wrong or the array of Filters I use?

But e.g. the first Filter (CIAccordionFoldTransition) seems to be a transition not really a filter. So it makes sense that it has a nil as output.

Is there a way to get all filters which are applicable to a single picture just like that?

I am pretty fresh in iOs and I hope my question isn't to stupid for this homepage, be kind!
Greetings and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the filters returned by `CIFilter.filterNamesInCategories` have an `inputImage` attribute, and some do not.

For example, the attributes understood by `CIAztecCodeGenerator` (mentioned in your exception report) are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAztecCodeGenerator), and `inputImage` isn't one of them.

A filter reports the keys for its input attributes through its [`inputKeys` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CIFilter/inputKeys). It describes all of its attributes through its [`attributes` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CIFilter/attributes).

Perhaps you want to restrict your filters to those that have an `inputImage` attributes:

```
let filterNames = CIFilter.filterNamesInCategories([kCICategoryStillImage,kCICategoryBuiltIn])
    .filter { CIFilter(name: $0)?.inputKeys.contains("inputImage") ?? false }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try that!    The accordion fold for example has an inputimage but i guess it has no Output (is nil) because it is a transition, is there a way to check that? Because the key is there, it just wont return anything. Maybe i should compile my own array with working filter using some catches?

Comment: yup thanks a lot your solution keeps out that one error, but i cant seem to find any list or explanation which filter does what... i just can try them out..

Comment: [Core Image Filter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346) (iOS edition).

Comment: yeah i got that, thats about.. i gues.. 300 filters, where just a small bit works on a single image. but well it seems i have to work them through. thanks anyway